# Memory issue regarding CCSprite initialization

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I would like to know if I do the following case, does that consider a leak?
How can I modify the codes so that it looks cleaner/better?

```
// ClassA
@interface ClassA
    CCSprite* image;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite* image;
@end

@implementation ClassA
@synthesize image;
- (id)init
{
    image = [[CCSprite alloc] init];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [image release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@interface Main
@end

@implementation Main
- (id)init
{
     ClassA* aObject = [[ClassA alloc] init];
     aObject.image = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"something.png"];
}
@end
```

Comment: whatever you do, dont call [image dealloc], instead you probably want to release it.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo.. I've edited it

Comment: Use ARC, use ARC, use ARC. Google the tutorials for enabling ARC and stop wondering, write your app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use same thing like this..see in ur code, twice memory allocated for image.

```
@interface ClassA : CCSprite
{

}

@end

@implementation ClassA
- (id)init
{

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    printf("Released..\n");
    [super dealloc];
}

@interface Main
@end

@implementation Main
- (id)init
{
     ClassA* aObject =  [ClassA spriteWithFile: @"something.png"];
     [self addChild:actor z:3 ];

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Yea I know that I'm allocating twice, but what I want to do is that image might not be assigned a spriteFile, depends on class... that's why locally in the classA, I want to initialise the spriteFile so that later it can be used by other class. How should I do this?
Can I do something like [image setImage: @"something.png"]; ?

Comment: First time use spriteWithFile and when u want to change then use setDisplayFrame: or setTexture:.